# Specific format for book review in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

I have to insert in the bibliography of a thesis some review to other work (also cited in the work, but this is not relevant). Unfortunately, the supervisor is veeery strict with his requests on bibliography formatting and I had to comply with a lot of particular guidelines.

I am using `biblatex` with biber backend in LuaLaTeX, and I will provide a MWE with all the modifications that I did to the bibliography.

Anyway, to the problem ahead: I want to add a review of a book. The requirement are that it should appear in the bibliography as (*rec. a* is the Italian for *review of*):

> [Author-of-review], rec. a [Full entry of reviewed book with standard formatting]; [rest of information on review]

I thought about creating an entirely new Bibliography Driver, but this looks way too much work: and actually I came across the *related* mechanism that is built in in biblatex. This seems perfect for what I want to do, except I can't get it to put the *parent* entry in the middle of the *child* one. In the MWE that follows, I show my best tentative hack, which unfortunately has some serious drawback as can easily be seen. Specifically, the hack in the `\newbibmacro{title}` correctly positions the reviewed work, but:

1. It doesn't (of course) remove the call at the end of the item
2. It works only on the first call (this I have no idea of why): in this case I have two reviews (`Meyer84` and `Meyer78`) but only `Meyer78` shows the reviewed title in the middle part
3. The punctuation sucks a little bit (this I think I can handle by myself with a bit of patience, but if someone can see something glaring, why not!).

Is there someone who can help me with this? Thank you a lot!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{scrbook}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Meyer84,
    author={Meyer, Paul},
    year={1884},
    journal={Romania},
    volume={XIII},
    pages={494-495},
    related={Hundgen},
    relatedtype={reviewof},
}

@book{Hundgen,
    author={H\"undgen, Franz},
    title={Das altprovenzalische Boëthiuslied},
    titleaddon={unter Beif\"ugung einer Uebersetzung, eines Glossars, erkl\"arender Anmerkungen sowie grammatischer und metrischer Untersunchungen herausgegeben},
    year={1884},
    location={Oppeln},
    publisher={Eugen Franck’s Buchhandlung},
}

@article{Boehmer, 
    author={Boehmer, Eduard},
    title={Zum Boeci},
    year={1878},
    journal={Romanische Studien},
    volume={III},
    pages={133-142}
}

@article{Meyer78,
    author={Meyer, Paul},
    year={1878},
    journal={Romania},
    volume={VII},
    pages={471},
    related={Boehmer},
    relatedtype={reviewof},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,
            maxalphanames=1,
            backend=biber,
            backref=false,
            maxcitenames=3,
            hyperref=true,
            dashed=false,
            url=false,
            doi=false,
            isbn=false,
            date=year]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\setlength\bibitemsep{2\itemsep}
\setlength\bibhang{2em}

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{}

\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{,\space}
\renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{\space}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{#1}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamesuffix}[1]{{#1}}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{given-family}
%\renewcommand{\multinamedelim}{\space--\space}
\renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}[0]{\addspace--\addspace}

%\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\space--\space}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{italian}{%
    reviewof = {rec. a}
}

\renewbibmacro*{date+extradate}{}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]{title}{\emph{#1\isdot}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{<<#1>>}
\DeclareFieldFormat{superedition}{\textsuperscript{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
    \printfield{issue}%
    \setunit{\space(}%
    \printdate)%
    \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
    \printlist{location}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \printlist{publisher}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \printdate%
    \newunit}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
    \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{\textnohyphenation{##1}}}%
    \defcounter{maxnames}{\blx@maxcitenames}%
    \printtext[]{\usebibmacro{cite}\addspace\par\nobreak}%
    \defcounter{maxnames}{\blx@maxbibnames}
    \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{##1}
    \renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}[0]{\addspace\addcomma\addspace}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
\iffieldundef{shorthand}%
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}%
        {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
            \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}%
        {\printnames{labelname}%
            \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}\printfield[superedition]{edition}%
    }%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}%
}

\newbibmacro*{title}{%
    \ifboolexpr{
        test {\iffieldundef{title}}
        and
        test {\iffieldundef{subtitle}}
    }%
    {\iffieldundef{related}{}{\usebibmacro{related}}}%
    {\printtext[title]{%
            \printfield[titlecase]{title}%
            \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
            \printfield[titlecase]{subtitle}}%
        \newunit%
        \printfield{titleaddon}}%
}

\newbibmacro*{revtitle}{%
    \ifboolexpr{
        test {\iffieldundef{title}}
        and
        test {\iffieldundef{subtitle}}
    }%
    {}%
    {\printtext[title]{%
            \printfield[titlecase]{title}%
            \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
            \printfield[titlecase]{subtitle}}%
    }%
}

\newbibmacro*{related:reviewof}[1]{%
    \entrydata*{#1}{%
        \iffieldundef{journaltitle}
        {\usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
            \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
            \usebibmacro{revtitle}%
            \newunit\newblock
            \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
            \newunit\newblock
            \printfield{edition}%
            \newunit
            \iffieldundef{volume}
            {}
            {\printfield{volume}%
                \printfield{part}}
            \newunit\newblock
            \usebibmacro{series+number}%
            \newunit\newblock
            \printfield{note}%
            \newunit\newblock
            \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
            \newunit\newblock
            \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}
        }
        {\usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
            \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
            \usebibmacro{title}%
            \newunit\newblock
            \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
            \newunit\newblock
            \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
            \newunit\newblock
            \usebibmacro{note+pages}
        }
    }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \cite{Hundgen,Meyer84}

    \cite{Boehmer,Meyer78}

    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: `the supervisor is veeery strict` – Why are you bleating :-)

Comment: I just want to cry! :'(

Comment: Not really relevant to the question, but if you use LuaLaTeX I don't see any good reason why you would want to write `\"u` instead of `ü` or `\"a` instead of `ä`. In fact you already use the non-ASCII char `ë`. I'd also remove the excess space in `author={Boehmer , Eduard},` to make the author field of `Boehmer` read just `Boehmer, Eduard`.

Comment: Yeah, it's just that I have the italian keyboard so it is not that easy to use non-ASCII char! I threw this MWE In a minute and it was faster this way! :)